# How to give a field value as key in mongo query?

Tags: mongodb

I have around more than 100k records. Below is my sample result which I need after running a query.

```
[{"code": {
  "xxx": {
     "yyy": ["877","8771"]
  },
     "ppp": ["877"] 
  },
  "ooo":{
   "ppp":["8772"]
   }
}]
```

[The collection](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FyhyS-KDP7c)

I tried using addToSet. Please help to find out a query

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @Ayoub Its pretty clear what OP wants to achieve. Wants values of a field as the keys in the grouping stage.

Comment: @RakshithMurukannappa Expected output is not valid Json. Clear the OP's question if you can

Comment: This is an interesting question but needs to be edited before I can give it an upvote.  @user1187 please add your Configuration to the question and change your sample result to some valid JSON that MongoDB could possibly produce.